# error 301 versus 410 when page deleted

Tags: seo, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301, google-search-console, http-status-code-410

before when I deleted a page, I was them redirected (301) this page to the category page, but in google webmastertool, it said that I had too many "soft 404"
so recently I changed this and send a 410 error and display some links to similar page, but now in webmastertool, it said that it found an increase of "404 not found"
what to do ??

Comment: 404 and 410 are more or less the same thing to the user for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they see an increase of 404 errors because that is what is happening! They warn you so that you notice unintended problems. But right now the increase is indeed intended so just ignore it. The warning will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do to not get people hitting deleted pages is to:

1. Stop deleting pages.
2. Clear out any links which may be leading to a deleted page.

If pages get deleted and links not removed then you'll be getting not found errors. Of course you can't avoid this if people are bookmarking your pages.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to see 404 error is to redirect this to the related pages but keep in mind that excessive use of redirects is also harm full.Try not to delete more pages and try to remove your links of this page or try to reduce the link and wait and ignore the 404 for this page as time pass it will be go down in google search results and you get know 404.